# Dynamic shape and # of layers based on placeholders in TensorfFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to create a shape based on a placeholder?

I have 2 use cases:

```
size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name="size")
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, size], name="x")
```

And:

```
shapes = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name="shapes")
tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    inputs=x, 
    num_outputs=shapes[-1]
)
```

The first one I guess I can "fix" with `[None, None]` (not sure about performance penalties in such a case).

For the second one I have no idea?

**The why:** I want to build and export the Graph using Python and then read it for training/predictions using the Java API. I don't want to prepare a file for every single hidden layer combination so I wanted to export only a single "template" graph, something like this:

```
def fc(x, shape):
    return tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=x, num_outputs=shape[-1])

def body(x, hidden_layers, i):
    # create a FC layer with shape=[hidden_layer[i], hidden_layer[i+1]]
    out = fc(x, [tf.slice(hidden_layers, [i], [1]), tf.slice(hidden_layers, [i+1], [1])])
    out = tf.tanh(out)

    return out, hidden_layers, i + 1

def condition(x, hidden_layers, i):
    return i < (len(hidden_layers) - 1)

# i.e. [200,200] or [50,50,50] etc.
hidden_layers = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], "hidden_layers")   
# loop counter
i = tf.constant(0, dtype='int32')    
# loop creating the network
out = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [x, hidden_layers, i])
```

And then the Java user would simply `feed` an array with the hidden network config. But I am getting `ValueError: ('num_outputs should be int or long, got %s.', <tf.Tensor 'while/fc/Slice_1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>)` when trying to generate the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think what you want is possible. What would happen with a dynamic number of hidden layers? Randomly spawning extra (untrained) layers is not something that is usual with neural networks.

Maybe clarifying your question would work. For example: lets say you either want to have two or three hidden layers, there are some possibilities. You could have two different sets of weights that either from layer two to layer X, or from layer two to layer three to layer X. If you want something like this, check tf.cond on this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/control_flow_ops

Good luck!

Comment: I want to prepare (and save for later reuse) a Graph where the user can specify how many hidden layers they want to use. The alternative (I'm using now) is to generate a file for each possible combination ([200], [200,200], [200,200, 200]) which is completely not feasible. I'm running this Graph via the Java API so generating it on the fly isn't an option unfortunately, I need to prepare it beforehand. It might be dangerous but if properly coded (with the number of hidden layers corresponding to the number of parameters) I don't see how this should not be possible from a technical standpoint.